JQuery Trigger click not triggering
I have a list of years and want to select the 1st element triggering a click but it's not working as I expect. This code gets me to the element on which I want to trigger a click on but it does nothing and there are no errors in the console.
$("#years > span > a").eq(0).trigger("click");

I've put this line of code on the last line in my JavaScript file, so my understanding is that after everything is loaded, the click should be triggered.
Why isn't this working as I expect?
Here is my html:
<div id="years">
  <span><a href="#">2023</a></span> <----- This is the one I want
  <span>•</span>
  <span><a href="#">2022</a></span>
  <span>•</span>
  <span><a href="#">2021</a></span>
  <span>•</span>
  <span><a href="#">2020</a></span>
</div>

It might help to know that the list of years are being built in the backend, so the HTML is complete when the page loads.
Here is my click handler:
$("#years > span > a").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url:'postsByYear.php',
    type:"GET",
    data:{
      year:$(this).text()
    },
    dataType:"html",
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('#view-posts').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).html(data).fadeIn(500);
        setMonths();
      });
    },
    error:function(error) {
      return alert('System Error');
    }
  });
});


Thank you for explaining that T.J. I'll post more code up top.

T.J. thanks for the help. As you can probably tell, front-end work isn't my forte. Sorry for that.
After the years are loaded into the HTML and JQuery runs, I would like my form to simply select the greatest year and click it so the form will populate with data. The way it works now, I have a message telling the user to click on a year. Then I concluded it would be easier for me to programmatically select the greatest year and be done with it. Im just trying to save the user 1 click

T.J. I do have a click handler for that element. It's basically an AJAX call to the server. I'll post that up top as well.

T.J. I've posted the click handler up top as well. I tried using $("#years > span > a").eq(0).trigger("click"); inside my success function but that doesn't work either. I didn't think I needed a handler to trigger a click

You don't need a handler to trigger click - you do need that click to do something - as it is, <a href="#"> doesn't do anything.  If you want your handler $("#years > span > a").on('click' to fire, then you need to make sure that line is before the trigger.  Providing separate code lines doesn't show us where anything is defined in relation to each other.  Start with a simple click handler, eg $("#years > span > a").on('click', () => console.log("click")); $("#years > span > a").trigger("click")

TBH you have a classic XY problem.  You want to do X (show the data for the latest year) and think the solution is Y (trigger a click event) so ask about how to trigger.  Instead, ask how to load the latest year on load (X).  The simplest solution is to move the ajax call to its own function, eg function getPostsByYear(year) { $.ajax(.. then call that function on startup, eg $(function() { getPostsByYear($("#years > span > a").text())

Thanks fdomm-m. I'll see if I can make that happen. I'm not a really big front-end guy but if I play with this long enough I should be able to get it working. Thanks for the diagnosis and the pointers. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it

In my case, all I had to do was trigger the click inside of the ready function. I was outside of it, so that's why it wasn't executing. In this case, it was my own oversight.
